# Querying across two tables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables "location" and "members".   Location contains member_id as a foreign key.   Member contains a boolean field "active".

I want to get all locations within a certain radius where member.active is true.

So far the following is succesfully getting the locations within the radius:

```
@locations = Location.near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance)
```

But I need to further filter this to show only active members.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am a complete RoR novice so apologies if the question is lacking some crucial information!

Comment: Try `Location.joins(:members).where(members: {active: true}).near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance)`

Comment: `near` is provided by geocoder isn't it? Worth adding that as a tag if so.

Comment: Octopus-Paul: I get a syntax error: /app/controllers/members_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...joins(:members).where(members: {active: true}).near(params[:... ^ /app/controllers/members_controller.rb:26: odd number list for Hash ...mbers).where(members: {active: true}).near(params[:location]... ^

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8? If so try using the old hash syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this-

```
   @locations = Location.joins(:members).near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance).where("active = 'true'")
```

or

```
   @locations = Location.joins(:members).near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance).find(:all, :conditions=>{:active =>'true'})
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I used a slightly modified version which works perfectly:

@locations = Location.joins(:member).near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance).where("active", true)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
Location.joins(:member).where(members: {active: true}).near(params[:location], 50, :order => :distance)
```

This is edited.

Comment: I get a syntax error: /app/controllers/members_controller.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...n.joins(:member).where(active: true).near(params[:location],... ^

Comment: Hi Alex, I have update this. Can you please check this.?